# General Integrals of Heaviside Function

Tags: calculus

Experimenting with Maple, it shows that

$\int H(x^2-1)dx = x-H(x+1)\cdot x-H(x+1)+H(x-1)\cdot x-H(x-1) +C $

Where $ H(x)=Heaviside(x) $

Now, differentiating is no problem at all, but integration is the thing that I have some trouble with here.
My initial approach is to state the following:

$[1]=\int H(x^2 -1)dx=H(x^2-1)\cdot x+H(x^2-1)\cdot C$
Under the conditions that
$[1](-1)=0 \land [1](1)=0$

This reasoning appears to work for heavisides containing polynomials of degree 1 or less, but appears not to work for higher degrees. The reason being that $[1](boundary) \neq 0$ in all cases.

So how do I go about integrating these functions generally?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a slick way of doing it but $H(x^2-1)$ is just $1$ for $x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$ and $0$ for $x\in(-1,1)$.  So $\int_0^x H(y^2-1)dy=\int_0^1 0 +\int_1^x 1 dy=x-1$ for $x>1$.  Once you write out the function piecewise, you could work out what it is in terms of Heaviside functions with trial and error.

Comment: How is it $x^2-1$ for the domain you gave, shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: Right.  That makes it easier.  I fixed it.